# Converting a returned SETOF into An Array in PL/PgSQL (specifically)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array-agg

I know there is the process of `SELECT array_agg(f) FROM (SELECT blah FROM stuff) f`, which is great in SQL, but when writing functions in PL/pgSQL, is there a shorthand method??

I'm trying to put JSON keys into an array I can use to look at the length.
Something like...

`v_len := array_length( array_agg(json_object_keys(myjson)), 1);`

instead of the long, DECLARE a variable, do a `SELECT array_agg(f) INTO ...`, which I've been doing.  I've seem hundreds of implementations using the same SQL string, but I really want to cut down my code, my fingers are going numb from all the redundant typing.

*What am I missing with that shorthand method?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a ARRAY(subselect) constructor

```
DO $$
DECLARE a int[];
BEGIN
  a := ARRAY(SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10));
  RAISE NOTICE 'result: %', a;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Awesome, knew it was something short and handy.   I ended up using you solution like so... `array_length( ARRAY( SELECT rs FROM json_object_keys(myjson) rs ), 1)`, which works beautifully to get the number of JSON keys.

Comment: @GuyPark: You can shorten `SELECT rs FROM json_object_keys(myjson) rs` to `SELECT json_object_keys(myjson)`

Comment: Cheers for that Nick